# Detect wether a point is inside a circle subset in a square

Tags: php, math, collision-detection

I need to plot images inside a circle on a grid.

See picture below of grid/circle.

[image: Example of grid]

The green circle is the container, no images should be plotted outside.

See example below. Purple squares = not placed, yellow squares = placed (As they're inside the green circle and they will fit).

The coloured squares represent the images that will be placed.

Squares are 50x50. While grid tiles are 100x100.

[image: Example where images should be placed.]

Currently, my program will generate the circle, grid and mark the X inside each grid tile, regardless of wether it is inside the container circle.

See below example of program working and placing images.

How could I work out if the image would fit inside the tile that is inside the circle.

The tile does not have to be 100% inside the circle. See the second image. See the tile on the bottom in the centre. The tile slightly protrudes the circle but the image 50x50 can still fit inside the tile.

Please see the function below that places the X inside each grid.
[image: Current implementation]

```
public function placeImages()
{
    $boxes = 5;
    $circumference = 700;
    $width = ($circumference / $boxes);

    $this->grid = array(
        array(
            'width'  =>
                array(
                    'x1' => 0,
                    'y1' => 0,
                    'x2' => 700,
                    'y2' => 0,
                ),
            'height' =>
                array(
                    'x1' => 0,
                    'y1' => 0,
                    'x2' => 0,
                    'y2' => 700,
                ),
        ),
        array(
            'width'  =>
                array(
                    'x1' => 0,
                    'y1' => 140,
                    'x2' => 700,
                    'y2' => 140,
                ),
            'height' =>
                array(
                    'x1' => 140,
                    'y1' => 0,
                    'x2' => 140,
                    'y2' => 700,
                ),
        ),
        array(
            'width'  =>
                array(
                    'x1' => 0,
                    'y1' => 280,
                    'x2' => 700,
                    'y2' => 280,
                ),
            'height' =>
                array(
                    'x1' => 280,
                    'y1' => 0,
                    'x2' => 280,
                    'y2' => 700,
                ),
        ),
        array(
            'width'  =>
                array(
                    'x1' => 0,
                    'y1' => 420,
                    'x2' => 700,
                    'y2' => 420,
                ),
            'height' =>
                array(
                    'x1' => 420,
                    'y1' => 0,
                    'x2' => 420,
                    'y2' => 700,
                ),
        ),
        array(
            'width'  =>
                array(
                    'x1' => 0,
                    'y1' => 560,
                    'x2' => 700,
                    'y2' => 560,
                ),
            'height' =>
                array(
                    'x1' => 560,
                    'y1' => 0,
                    'x2' => 560,
                    'y2' => 700,
                ),
        ),
        array(
            'width'  =>
                array(
                    'x1' => 0,
                    'y1' => 700,
                    'x2' => 700,
                    'y2' => 700,
                ),
            'height' =>
                array(
                    'x1' => 700,
                    'y1' => 0,
                    'x2' => 700,
                    'y2' => 700,
                ),
        ),
    );

    //This removes the grid item for the bottom and right lines, not needed within the loop.
    array_pop($this->grid);

    foreach ($this->grid as $grid) {
        $x = $grid['width']['x1'];
        $y = $grid['width']['y1'];

        for ($j = 0; $j < $boxes; $j++) {
            $this->drawLine($x, $y, ($x + $width), ($y + $width), '#ff3200');
            $this->drawLine(($x + $width), $y, $x, ($y + $width), '#ff3200');

            //50 × 50 = Image size
            $imageX = floor($x + ($width - 50) / 2);
            $imageY = floor($y + ($width - 50) / 2);;


            $image = Image::make(base_path('test.png'))->opacity(50);

            $this->image->insert($image, 'top-left', $imageX, $imageY);

            $x = $x + $width;
        }
    }
}
```

The code above is a simplified version of my program. The grid array is dynamically generated, but I don't think this matters for this question.

Comment: I've seen you update, play with margins. Create a variable $margin, and recalculate: $width=$width-$margin. Play with that until you're satisfied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This equation satisfies whenever the point is inside a circle:

> (x - center_x)^2 + (y - center_y)^2 < radius^2

So you should check it before inserting the image.

For all corners you would only check one of them, depending on the quarter of the chart you are. f.e, upper right quarter, image_x would be $x, image_y would be $y (whitout resting the width and dividing by 2). For down left quarter, -$x, $-y.

More detailed, checking bounds. Considering that the circle is placed at (0,0) and with a radius of 700:

```
$bounding_x = $x;
$bounding_y = $y;

if($x > 0)
   $bounding_x += width;

if($x < 0)
   $bounding_x -= width;

if($y > 0)
   $bounding_y += width;

if($y < 0)
   $bounding_y -= width;

if ($bounding_x*$bounding_x + $bounding_y*$bounding_y < 490000)
//....insert image
```

Comment: You need to check for all four corners.

Comment: not exactly, this aproach would check only the center of the square. For all corners you would only check one of them, depending on the quarter of the chart you are. f.e, upper right quarter, image_x would be $x, image_y would be $y (whitout resting the width and dividing by 2). For down left quarter, -$x, $-y.

Comment: Checking just the center is not enough (or is inaccurate if you prefer). And indeed you can micro-optimize the four corner test.

Comment: This does not seem to work as expected. It only matches the bottom right corner.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/vvOeV.jpg

Comment: How is the 490000 calculated?

Answer (score 1):

The basic theory for finding if a square is inside a circle is to check if all four corners of it falls within the circle. This is true for both your tiles and image placeholders.

**Properties of the circle**

You need to find the radius (r) and the center(cx, cy) first. If we consider your top-right corner is (0, 0) then:

```
radius = circumference / (pi * 2)    //considering 2(pi)r = circumference

cx, cy = (r, -r)    //your center is r away from the top-right
```

**Detecting**

Now you should go through your array and see if all the corners of all the tiles fall within the circle. Lets see how to detect if a single point falls within the circle.

```
function withinCircle(x, y) {       

   return ((r - x)*(r - x) + (y - r)*(y - r) < r * r) ;       

}
```

The function tests if the `x` or `y` coordinate of the point is outside the radius. The fact that your circle is in the range of 270-360 range of the plane is considered for signs.

Comment: You are testing point inside square, not point inside circle !

Answer (score 0):

You can test if the corners of the squares are inside the circle.
if one vertex of the square is (a,b),
you will not be able to plot it is sqrt(a^2+b^2) > radius.

This is assuming the center of the circle has coordinates (0,0), if that is not the case, and the circle has coordinates (x,y), we need to move all the points by (-x,-y), in this case the test is:

sqrt((a-x)^2+(b-y)^2) > radius.

Comment: You need to take into account the center of the circle.